# Generate permutations without duplicated elements in both rows and colums

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, permutation, combinatorics

I have 4 teams (A-D) and 4 games (1-4).

GOAL: I want to generate a dataframe (4,4) :

- that has 4 rows for 4 rounds
- that has 4 columns for 4 games
- I want to attribute a different team to each column/game over these 4 rows/rounds
- and I DON'T want duplicates in either rows or columns

I get how to do permutations, and I know how to avoid duplicates in each row, but I'm stuck when trying to avoid duplicates in both rows and columns.

In the end, I want to get a dataframe like this (no duplicates horizontally or vertically):

```
A B C D

B D A C

D C B A

C A D B
```

And obviously, in reality I have way more games and teams !

Can someone help me with that please ?

Thank you!

---

**edit:**

Thanks to all of you ! Super useful.

I also would like to be able to fix some positions in the output that I get (the final one being with 12 games and 12 teams).

For example, I'd like to be able to specify several fixed positions such as : *B must be in position (1,2)* **AND** *D must be in position (4,3)*, **AND** *etc*.

Any idea how to get latin squares that also meet these conditions ?

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is equivalent to cycling through the vector. I.e. start with ABCD, shift one over for BCDA, etc. We can do that e.g. like so:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:4]
sapply(seq_along(x), \(i) x[c(i:length(x), seq_len(i - 1))])
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
> [2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A" 
> [3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B" 
> [4,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
> ```

Comment: This is deterministic, however. I think the TO wants the order to be randomized.

Comment: That's not clear to me, but if so, one can shuffle either the rows or the column, e.g. `result[sample(nrow(result)), ]`.

Comment: Yep, I wanted to propose that solution. But maybe you could just add it as an alternative? Ideally, you could shiffle through rows AND columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Easy.
Would you know how to fix some specific positions by any chance (see edit) ?

Answer (score 4):

No duplicates in either row or column sounds like a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) to me.

The `magic` package could be of help with this

```
magic::rlatin(n = 3)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    1    3
#> [2,]    1    3    2
#> [3,]    3    2    1
```

And for your example, we can use an already existing `x` with letters or team names and convert to a data frame afterwards.

```
x <- LETTERS[1:4]
as.data.frame(matrix(x[magic::rlatin(length(x))], nrow = length(x)))
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4
#> 1  D  B  A  C
#> 2  A  D  C  B
#> 3  B  C  D  A
#> 4  C  A  B  D
```

Depends on the use-case if you want to require a whole other package, especially when a good answer on how to do this in base R has already been submitted.

Comment: Thank you !! And thanks, I didn't know the name of that configuration, which made it really annoying to google... 
I couldn't find an argument in latin() that would allow me to fix some specific positions in the dataframe I get. Do you know if it exists ?

Answer (score 4):

## One Random Instance

If you only one random instance of the desired Latin square matrix, you can define a function like below

```
RandLatinSqr <- function(v) {
    # check if the resulting matrix is valid
    checker <- function(m) {
        all(table(m, col(m)) == 1)
    }
    #  repeat random generation until one valid matrix occurs
    repeat {
        m <- t(replicate(length(v), sample(v)))
        if (checker(m)) {
            return(m)
        }
    }
}
```

or a lighter (***more efficient***) version with `embed`

```
RandLatinSqr2 <- function(v) {
    embed(
        rep(v, length.out = 2 * length(v) - 1),
        length(v)
    )[sample(seq_along(v)), ]
}
```

and you can obtain a matrix like

```
> RandLatinSqr(LETTERS[1:4])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"

> RandLatinSqr2(LETTERS[1:4])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"
```

---

## All Valid Matrices

If you don't have a large number of teams, you definitely can use a brute-force method to enumerate all Latin squares. Since you have only **`4`** teams, I don't think it will consume too much time for all permutations, i.e., `choose(prod(1:4), 4) * prod(1:4) = 255024` permutations.

For example, we can run the code below

```
library(pracma)
AllLatinSqr <- function(v) {
    L <- perms(v) # all permutations of above 4 teams

    # check if the resulting matrix is valid
    checker <- function(m) {
        all(table(m, col(m)) == 1)
    }

    # all valid matrices
    unlist(Filter(
        length,
        combn(1:nrow(L),
            length(v),
            FUN = \(x) {
                m <- L[x, ]
                if (checker(m)) {
                    apply(
                        perms(1:nrow(m)),
                        1,
                        \(k) m[k, ],
                        simplify = FALSE
                    )
                }
            }, simplify = FALSE
        )
    ), recursive = FALSE)
}
```

or a ***more efficient*** version based on `RandLatinSqr2` ***(due to the fact that all Latin squares are homogeneously mutable in the sense of row-/column-wise permutations)***

```
AllLatinSqr2 <- function(v) {
    RandLatinSqr2 <- function(v) {
        embed(
            rep(v, length.out = 2 * length(v) - 1),
            length(v)
        )[sample(seq_along(v)), ]
    }

    m <- RandLatinSqr2(v)
    L <- asplit(perms(seq_along(v)), 1)
    unlist(lapply(L, \(i) lapply(L, \(j) m[i, j])), recursive = FALSE)
}
```

or you can define a custom function (base R) like below

```
AllLatinSqr3 <- function(v) {
    # check valid values to fill in the given position of matrix
    checker <- function(mat, i, j, v) {
        setdiff(v, na.omit(c(mat[i, ], mat[, j])))
    }
    
    # help to generate all possible matrices
    helper <- function(m, idx, v) {
        l <- length(v)
        i <- (idx - 1) %/% l + 1
        j <- (idx - 1) %% l + 1
        u <- checker(m, i, j, v)
        lapply(u, \(x) {
            m[i, j] <- x
            m
        })
    }

    # initial value
    lst <- list(matrix(NA, length(v), length(v)))
    cnt <- 1
    repeat {
        lst <- unlist(
            lapply(
                lst,
                helper,
                idx = cnt,
                v = v
            ),
            recursive = FALSE
        )
        if (cnt == length(v)^2) {
            return(lst)
        } else {
            cnt <- cnt + 1
        }
    }
}
```

### Benchmarking

```
v <- LETTERS[1:3]
microbenchmark(
    AllLatinSqr(v),
    AllLatinSqr2(v),
    AllLatinSqr3(v),
    unit = "relative"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: relative
            expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
  AllLatinSqr(v) 25.35247 22.62071 16.718686 22.735617 23.99345 1.801778   100
 AllLatinSqr2(v)  1.00000  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000 1.000000   100
 AllLatinSqr3(v) 13.23587 10.86634  8.252907  9.725716 10.83098 3.323076   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas ! 
Do you know if there would be a simple way to add a functionality that would allow to specify some fixed positions in the matrices that we get ? (see my edit)

Comment: @Hal see another answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/77047658/12158757

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your latest edit of the question with constraints, e.g., `B` and `D` are fixed in the positions `(1,2)` and `(4,3)`, respectively, you can have the following two variants based on `AllLatinSqrtConstr2` and `AllLatinSqrtConstr3`.

Note that, the similar idea can be applied to `RandLatinSqr`, thus be skipped in this answer.

## Code

```
AllLatinSqrConstr2 <- function(v) {
    RandLatinSqr2 <- function(v) {
        embed(
            rep(v, length.out = 2 * length(v) - 1),
            length(v)
        )[sample(seq_along(v)), ]
    }

    constrFilter <- function(m) {
        m[1, 2] == "B" && m[4, 3] == "D"
    }

    m <- RandLatinSqr2(v)
    L <- asplit(perms(seq_along(v)), 1)

    Filter(
        constrFilter,
        unlist(lapply(L, \(i) lapply(L, \(j) m[i, j])), recursive = FALSE)
    )
}
```

or

```
AllLatinSqrConstr3 <- function(v) {
    # check valid values to fill in the given position of matrix
    checker <- function(mat, i, j, v) {
        setdiff(v, na.omit(c(mat[i, ], mat[, j])))
    }

    # help to generate all possible matrices
    helper <- function(m, idx, v) {
        l <- length(v)
        i <- (idx - 1) %/% l + 1
        j <- (idx - 1) %% l + 1
        if (is.na(m[i, j])) {
            u <- checker(m, i, j, v)
            lapply(u, \(x) {
                m[i, j] <- x
                m
            })
        } else {
            list(m)
        }
    }

    # initial value
    m <- matrix(NA, length(v), length(v))
    m[1, 2] <- "B"
    m[4, 3] <- "D"
    lst <- list(m)
    cnt <- 1
    repeat {
        lst <- unlist(
            lapply(
                lst,
                helper,
                idx = cnt,
                v = v
            ),
            recursive = FALSE
        )
        if (cnt == length(v)^2) {
            return(lst)
        } else {
            cnt <- cnt + 1
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

Given input data `v <- LETTERS[1:4]`

```
> AllLatinSqrConstr2(v)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D" 
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[9]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C" 

[[10]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[11]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[12]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[13]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[14]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[15]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[16]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[17]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[18]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[19]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[20]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[21]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B" 

[[22]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[23]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[24]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[25]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[26]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[27]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D" 
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[28]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[29]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[30]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[31]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[32]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"
```

and

```
> AllLatinSqrConstr3(v)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B" 
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A" 
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[9]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[10]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[11]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[12]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[13]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[14]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[15]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "A"  "C"  "B"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A" 

[[16]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "D"
[2,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[17]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[18]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B" 
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[19]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "B"  "A"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[20]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A" 
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[21]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[22]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "C"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"

[[23]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[24]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "A"  "C"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "B"  "A"
[3,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[25]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[26]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"

[[27]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "A"  "D"  "B"  "C"
[3,] "B"  "C"  "A"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[28]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "C"  "A"  "D"
[3,] "A"  "D"  "B"  "C"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[29]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "C"  "A"  "D"  "B"

[[30]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[3,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[31]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "D"  "A"  "C"
[4,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "B"

[[32]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "D"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"
[4,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "C"
```